# How to label multiple date in Full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Full calendar JavaScript Plugin in my PHP project. Project is a Job Schedule Application where i am assigning a job to a person for 2 days for example 1.12.2019 to 3.12.2019.

i want to show that Job in calendar  labeling from 1.12.2019 to 3.12.2019 in a single color.

Comment: Take care with your spelling. http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Why can't you achieve that currently? It sounds like you just need to create one event covering that whole time period. Please add more information to your question which clarifies precisely what difficulty you're facing when achieving your goal.